# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DocuSign\eSign\ApiException' with message '[401] when trying to go live

Tags: php, web-services, docusignapi

I am trying to move my docusign implementation from the demo account to the production one, but when I try to make a login request I receive the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DocuSign\eSign\ApiException' with message '[401] Error connecting to the API (https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/8159635/envelopes)' in ......
```

I haven't experienced any problems with the developer account and I my implementation was approved by dicusign and the integration key was assigned to the official account.

I'm using the following PHP implementation - https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client

I changed the host in the code from "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi" to "https://www.docusign.net/restapi"

Any help will be really appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: 401 means unauthorized. We'll need to see more of your flow to see what's missing.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're calling the wrong endpoint; try na3.docusign.net/restapi/v2/...

Comment: thanks! this works!! Dunno why it's not been accepted. had exact same issue and couldn't find any documentation anywhere to help! Lifesaver!!